# Textbox is not turning red in Form Validation Angular 2

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular2-forms

So i have a really weird problem. I am using Ionic with Angular 2 for my Form validation. If i click on the textbox the validation appears but the textbox is not turning red but whenever i click away and click on the textbox again it turns red so after 2 clicks it turns red and i don't know the solution for this.

Form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form"
      (ngSubmit)="addUser(form)">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"
               formControlName="username"
               required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <div *ngIf="form.get('username').touched && form.get('username').invalid"
       class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('required')">Naam moet ingevuld zijn.</div>
    <div *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('pattern')">Ongeldige naam.</div>
    <div *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('minLength')">Minder dan 5 letters gebruikt</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And my validation:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-z ]+') /*, Validators.minLength(3)*/
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5)
      ]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email])
    });
  }
```